# How to create a dataflow job in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-dataflow

Whenever I am creating a dataflow job, it is giving an error as below. Am I missing something?

```
"Unable to parse template file 'gs://ai-datascience/script/gcs_orc_snowflake.py'.

Error details:

[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
    "violations": [
      {
        "type": "JSON",
        "subject": "0:0",
        "description": "Unexpected end of stream : expected '{'"
      }
    ]
  }
]
Tracking number: c5631041776539207"
```

I followed the steps as per the google doc but no luck.
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#creating-and-staging-a-classic-template

Comment: Can you share the command line you executed that causes this error ?

Comment: python -m gcs_orc_snowflake \
 --runner DataflowRunner \
 --project PROJECT_ID \
 --staging_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/staging \ 
 --temp_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/temp \
 --template_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/script/gcs_orc_snowflake.py \
 --region us-central1

Comment: Any thoughts on the error is appreciated

Comment: On your side you replace `BUCKET_NAME` by the real name of your bucket ?

Comment: Yes, just for privacy. Made changes in the above error message

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the template path is incorrect. Possibly an environment variable was not used correctly when you ran the pipeline ?

It should have used the actual GCS bucket name in the path instead of "BUCKET_NAME".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check your bucket path and if the Python template file exists :

```
gs://BUCKET_NAME/script/gcs_orc_snowflake.py
```

In your example you indicated `BUCKET_NAME` in the command line and also in the error message, please test your command with the real bucket name in all the program arguments from your command line and be sure that your Python template file exists in the specified location.

If your bucket path is correct and the Python template file exists, check if the content of this file is correct (Python code well indented and without errors).

Comment: Does that also mean I need to follow the entire structure of WordCount sample example to work and execute a pipeline as a job? I have googled so many solutions wherein most of them suggested following the sample example structure.                                                    Can you share a sample python script (except WordCount) with all the necessary code to execute as a job in dataflow?

Comment: Ok I will update my answer with a real example of Dataflow job.